# How can `animation-play-state` in CSS be initially set to `paused` and changed to `running`?

Tags: css, css-animations

Using CSS and HTML, a checkbox, an `index` and a `content` div were created.
The `index` has a fixed position and is floated floated at the left.
The `content` adjusts its width to the available space and thus takes its place next to `index`.
The `checkbox` toggles between two states:
`:not(:checked)` moves the index and content to the right.
`:checked` moves the index and content to the left, pushing `index` off-screen.

These moves are CSS3 animations: `moveindexleft`, `movecontentleft`, `moveindexright` and `movecontentright`.
`index` and `content` have their `animation-play-state` initially set at `paused`. Ticking the `checkbox` changes that to `running`. This is to prevent the animation being played right after the initial loading of the page.

Testing in Firefox 42.0 and Chromium 47.0.2526.80 (64-bit), the issue is that this initial `animation-play-state: paused` is ignored.

The result: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmzyxzhs/

How can `animation-play-state` in CSS be initially set to `paused` and changed to `running`?

N.b.: If initially set to `animation-play-state: paused !important;`, then the checkbox toggle does not override this, disabling all animations.

Additionally, there seems to be a slight delay after clicking on the checkbox and initiating the animation. Can this be optimized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no problem with the `animation-play-state` property and none of the browsers ignore it. The problem that you are facing is because of the selectors and the way they work. The `:not(:checked)` selector would match the original/default state of your checkbox also because, well, it is not selected. This combined with the fact that that the `:not(:checked)` selector appears later in your CSS file and that it has more specificity than `div#index` or `div#content` selector makes the animation play state setting defined within this `:not(:checked)` selector (which is `running`) take precedence. This is the reason why the animation is getting executed on page load also.

As far as I am aware you cannot achieve both (a) pause the animation on load and (b) have a reverse animation when the checkbox is not checked using CSS selectors alone. At any given point, you can get only one of those to work.

Hence, the recommended solution for you would be to use JavaScript (or any preferred libraries) and add a class to the element the very first time the user clicks on the checkbox. Then the `:checked` or `:not(:checked)` styling can be applied only when the checkbox has this extra class.

```js
var chkBox = document.getElementById('toggle');

chkBox.addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.classList.add('user-interacted');
});
```

```css
div#index {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
  left: 0em;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
div#content {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 10em;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
@keyframes moveindexleft {
  0% {
    left: 0em;
  }
  100% {
    left: -10em;
  }
}
@keyframes movecontentleft {
  0% {
    margin-left: 10em;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0em;
  }
}
@keyframes moveindexright {
  0% {
    left: -10em;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0em;
  }
}
@keyframes movecontentright {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0em;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 10em;
  }
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

/* note the change in selectors */
input[type=checkbox].user-interacted:not(:checked) ~ div#index {
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-name: moveindexright;
}
input[type=checkbox].user-interacted:not(:checked) ~ div#content {
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-name: movecontentright;
}
input[type=checkbox].user-interacted:checked ~ div#index {
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-name: moveindexleft;
}
input[type=checkbox].user-interacted:checked ~ div#content {
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-name: movecontentleft;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<label for="toggle">
  Button
</label>

<input id="toggle" type=checkbox>
<div id="index">
  index
</div>

<div id="content">
  content
</div>
```

---

Alternately, you can achieve the same effect by just using CSS `transition` (as pointed out by [vals in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344692/how-can-animation-play-state-in-css-be-initially-set-to-paused-and-changed-t#comment56444149_34348628)). Transitions get triggered only when user clicks on the checkbox (unlike `animation` which starts automatically on page load). Below is a sample snippet for this approach.

```css
div#index {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
  left: 0em;
  transition: left 1s linear;
}
div#content {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 10em;
  transition: margin-left 1s linear;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) ~ div#index {
  left: 0em;
}
input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) ~ div#content {
  margin-left: 10em;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div#index {
  left: -10em;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div#content {
  margin-left: 0em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<label for="toggle">
  Button
</label>

<input id="toggle" type=checkbox>
<div id="index">
  index
</div>

<div id="content">
  content
</div>
```

Comment: ... but the request can be achieved with transitions (at least in this case). Good answer by the way.

Comment: Thanks @vals and yes you make a very valid point. I was just thinking of an `animation` and didn't give a thought to `transition`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Harry and vals, for your fine solutions.

Comment: @rayanamukami: You're welcome. Glad that I could help :)